# Calculate the time of a ball from a to b

Tags: physics

I want to build an automated pinball game.
The plan is to place two light barriers (A and B) on the field. The time from A to B is measured and then the needed time from B to the flipper arm(s) C is calculated.

An idealized environment is assumed. By that I mean that I assume rolling without slipping or sliding. I assume no friction.

$$s = \frac{1}{2} \cdot a \cdot t^2 + v_0 \cdot t + s_0$$
$$t_{BC} = \frac{2 \cdot (s - s_0)}{v_{max} + 2 \cdot v_0}$$
$$t_{BC} = \frac{2 \cdot (s_2)}{v_{max} + 2 \cdot v_0}$$

By the law of conversation of energy I come up with
$$m \cdot g \cdot h = \frac{1}{2} \cdot m \cdot v^2 + \frac{1}{2} / w^2$$
$$v_{max} = \sqrt{g \cdot h \cdot \frac{10}{7}}$$

and

$$v_0 = \frac{s_B - s_A}{t_B - t_A}$$

The idea is to measure the current velocity in point B and use it as $v_0$ to calculate the needed time from B to C.

My questions are pretty simple:
Is my idea correct? I'm mostly uncertain if I'm allowed to assume $v_0$ in the way I'm doing it here.
If not: what would be the better way?
If it's somehow correct: What are possible uncertainities by idealizing the setting in that way?

After getting a few questions:
I prepeared a little drawing and a photo to make it more clear, unfortunately I don't have the reputation to upload any images. Here is a second try: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRE1U.jpg)

The field I'm using is actually using this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YbeXRZl8hlM
But I use only the building blocks and photo transistors. The "magic" is done using an FPGA.

My worry is if the basic concept is correct at all and if I can calculate the time from B to C in the way I want to do it.

Comment: Is this like for a pinball game? Maybe you could explain the set-up a bit more; it's a bit unclear to me. Are you worried about the angular momentum of a rolling ball? Sliding of the ball on the surface?

Comment: "Pinball game" is indeed a more precise term for the global device than "flippers" which are only a part of it. Is the board considered as flat ?